# send json via paypal.request.post() from PayPal checkout.js

Tags: json, ajax, paypal

```
paypal.Button.render({
    payment: function() {
        var booksPurchaseRequest = {};
        booksPurchaseRequest.amount = 20;
        return paypal.request
                            .post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL, JSON.stringify(booksPurchaseRequest))
                            .then(function(data) {
                                return data.paymentId;
                            });
    }
}, '#paypal-button');
```

In such approach on back-end server I'm receiving data in **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** format, but I need **application/json**. How can I achieve that? Can paypal.request.post() be replaced with simple $.ajax()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return paypal.request({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/foo/bar',
    json: {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
}).then(function(response) {

})
```

Or you can just use jQuery, you just need to return a promise

Comment: where is the documentation on this?